# C# Scientific calculation - big number with many decimals

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I have a problem that I need advice: I have to make calculations with big numbers, in the range of (*plus/minus, signed*); integer part: `70*(10^27)` and accuracy, decimal part: `9*(10^-31)`. Most of the times I only simple simple operations (add/subtr/mult/div) where I could ignore most digits (use only 8 decimals) of the decimal part - however, in many cases, I would have to take the 'whole' decimal and do calculations with that precision (and store the result which is used in subsequent calculations).
An example of a number:

> 66898832014839425790021345548 **.** 8499970865478385639546957014538

I saw the articles on decimal vs long etc. Should I use a decimal or should a custom type be made? If yes on the later, how may I do simple arithmetic operations? (Roundation of the last decimal only is acceptable)
My projects are all in C# and SQL Server; thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Afaik there's no standard type that supports 60 decimals of precision.

Comment: out of curiosity - can i ask what kind of calculations require this grade of precision (i mean - that's the order of magnitude to map the whole known universe down to a planck length)? also, you might wanna use something like [BigDecimal](https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: thank you for the suggestion, I didn't new about BigDecimal, will look it up. The data are coming from external sources, some from MATLAB (my guess only) and are part of a Blockchain simulation algorithm. It is not mining and such, they will be used for digital signatures (another project, not mine). Unfortunately, I am not an expert and I have already some code for some operations, but not for data like that (so many digits... both in integer and decimal part)

Comment: It looks like Matlab has a library (see https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/05/22/quadruple-precision-128-bit-floating-point-arithmetic/).  So I would do all the math in Matlab and return a string in c# to display results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard implementation in C#, but you can create your own library based on [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0) like

```
public BigDecimal(BigInteger integer, BigInteger scale)
```

You can also reference some 3rd-party libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) with its .Net forks/ports like [Math.Gmp.Native.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Math.Gmp.Native.NET/), [libgmp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libgmp_vc120/), etc.

There are some custom libs, as Franz Gleichmann already mentioned in his comment: [BigDecimal](https://gist.github.com/JcBernack/0b4eef59ca97ee931a2f45542b9ff06d), [AngouriMath](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngouriMath)

For SQL Server most of the libraries use strings to store such kind of data. For instance, in Java there is [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and it is mapped to string via [JDBC](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/787).

Comment: that's absolutely great, thank you very much, I will give it a try immediately!